# Position of text in mobile version of web page

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have a slider, and text inside it, and I need to make this text responsive. I mean in computer version it looks like as I want, but in mobile version it shifts and I can`t see my icons under each other.

css:

```
.sliderr__item .slid{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
/*END*/

.sliderr {
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
.sliderr__wrapper {
    display: flex;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease;
    /* ADDED: */
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.sliderr__item {
    flex: 0 0 50%;  
}

.sliderr .date {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 1em;
}

/* Added: */
.sliderr__controls {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: row;
}
.sliderr__control {
  /* Added: */
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* Updated: */
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 25px;
  /* The Same: */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  height: 25px;
  background: #5FA467;
  /*
    REMOVED: transform: translateY(-50%);
  */
}
```

html:

```
<div class="sliderr"><br>
    <div class="sliderr__wrapper">
    <div class="sliderr__item" style="border: 1px solid #DCE2EC;">
      <div style="height: 150px;" class="slid">
          <p style="font-family: Roboto; font-size: 14px; color: #5FA467;">My first text</p><br>
          <p style="font-family: Roboto; font-size: 16px; color: #000; font-weight: bold;">My second text</p><br> 
          <p style="display: inline-block; font-family: Roboto; font-size: 14px; color: #000;"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/20" style="width: 18px; height: 18px;"><span>My User</span><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/20" style="margin-left: 20px;">  21.08.2018</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sliderr__item" style="border: 1px solid #DCE2EC;">
      <div style="height: 150px;" class="slid">
          <p style="font-family: Roboto; font-size: 14px; color: #5FA467;">My first text</p><br>
          <p style="font-family: Roboto; font-size: 16px; color: #000; font-weight: bold;">My second text</p><br> 
          <p style="display: inline-block; font-family: Roboto; font-size: 14px; color: #000;"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/20" style="width: 18px; height: 18px;"><span>My User</span><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/20" style="margin-left: 20px;">  21.08.2018</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

So, I have 3 paragraph of text and in mobile version I need to see them in the center and under each other and icons need to be under each others with their text. How can I make that? Full sample in this JSFiddle `https://jsfiddle.net/ofzpnL2k/4/`

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS media queries to achieve different stylink for mobile. It's like `if` conditionals for CSS.

Here you can find more explanation about it: https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp.